# How to choose with a different way the OSM Boundaries

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, borders

I need to get the borders of a country via Overpass API, but with the following query

```
relation
  ["boundary"="administrative"]
  ["admin_level"="2"]
  ["name:en"="some country for example Papua New Guinea"];
(._;>;);
out body;
```

I get the marine borders also, and not only the borders of the terrain I want, any solution for that?

Comment: I get borders that are also on the sea, and I want only the perimeter of the terrain for example of some islands, this is what I mean

Comment: One example would be Germany where there are two different relations (http://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/1111111 and http://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/51477) but no tags to distinguish them from each other :\

Comment: have you seen [OpenStreetMapData](http://openstreetmapdata.com/data/coast)? There are sea/land polygons which you could use to clip the boundaries.

Comment: @scai Nowadays land area relation is tagged with type=land_area (relation for Germany is now at https://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/62781 )

Answer (score 1):

You can filter out [Maritime](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:boundary%3Dmaritime) tag (skip all with maritime=yes).